# How to find some text and replace the value in a DataFrame column using python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the follow DataFrame in my code:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Sub-123 | foco |
| Sub-321 | #foco, teste |
| Sub-332 | Foco, cod |

I need to find the rows that have "Foco" in the "Column B" and replace to "Foco" to be:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Sub-123 | Foco |
| Sub-321 | Foco |
| Sub-332 | Foco |

How can I create it using Python and Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) (and `case=False`):

```
df.loc[df['Column B'].str.contains('foco', case=False), 'Column B'] = 'Foco'
```

Output:

```
  Column A Column B
0  Sub-123     Foco
1  Sub-321     Foco
2  Sub-332     Foco
```